# Preventing multiple tasks updating the same TSQ

Tags: mainframe, cics

I have one TSQ in my program to keep an OKTA token which expires after every 8 hour.
The TSQ record will have token value and Expiration timestamp.
On Expiry of the token, the program calls the OKTA WEB APIs and get a new token and updates the TSQ with new token.

This program can be called many times in a second. How I can prevent multiple Tran/tasks updating the tsq when the token expires?

Currently I am exploring the option of ENQ and DEQ. Can someone advice me that will be a better option ?

Any different thoughts other than TSQ also fine

Thinking to try the below code

working-storage.
01 ws-tsq-name   x(16)

PROCEDURE DIVISION.

```
a100-token-expiry section.

read the token tsq 

if token expired or tsq doesnt exist
  perform a200-get-token. 
end-if
```

a100-exit.
exit.

```
a200-get-token section.
   exec cics enq 
        resource (ws-tsq-name)
        length(length of ws-tsq-name)
        nosuspend 
        resp(ws-resp1)
        resp2 (ws-resp2)
        
   end-exec
 if ws-resp2  = dfhresp(enqbusy)
     set ws-enqbusy to true
 end-if
 
 if ws-enqbusy
    link to okta token api program and get the token
    pass the token to caller
else
  link to okta token api program and get the token
  create/update the tsq
  pass the token to caller
     exec cics deq 
        resource (ws-tsq-name)
        length(length of ws-tsq-name)
        resp(ws-resp1)
        resp2 (ws-resp2)
        
   end-exec
  
end-if
```